# angular ui router redirect using url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('check', {
        url:'/check',
        templateUrl: 'views/List.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'

      })

$state.go('check')
```

works but

```
location.href='/check'
```

doesn't. With this I get:

```
 Cannot GET /check/
```

**If I reload the page, then also it results in Cannot GET error but works only if redirected by `$state.go`**

I basically want to be able to load the page when that URL is hit no matter if it was hit through code or reloaded through the browser. Browser reload seems to fail always.

How do I trigger a particular state when redirected to a url?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```

html5 mode is enabled so url should work fine.

Comment: Did you try `$location.path('/check');` ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Controller. But the thing is if I reload the page, it still throws Cannot GET /check

Comment: @MaximShoustin: I did. Works initially. but on page reload I get Cannot GET /check.

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Because on page reload, it does not work. check was for demo  purposes actually. My real url looks like /views/:firstparam/:secondparam. I am structuring this url in code and would like to hit it directly through code and browser but reload fails in either cases.

Comment: In which component did you define `$locationProvider`? Run, Config, controller?

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: In which component did you define $locationProvider
>
> A: Controller.

---

#### Short answer

The best practice is to define `$stateProvider` into `module.config` It will guarantee that *states* will be loaded before any module controller.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // ...
}
```

---

In your case, you call URL before controller is loaded and therefore no state is defined. This is a reason why you got error `Cannot GET /check/`

[See References](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)